# Unable to generate jars from LUCENE-2899.patch

Tags: git, solr, lucene

Sorry for asking a duplicate, but I couldn't find any substantial info for my problem.

I am trying to apply LUCENE-2899.patch to solr(https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP#Installation).

I cloned *master* from *https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/releases/lucene-solr/6.3.0/solr*. Later from git bash, I invoked  *patch -p1 -i LUCENE-2899.patch*   from the parent directory which contains "dev-tools, lucene,solr, build.xml"     (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Working_With_Patches). 
It gives me following errors:

```
patching file dev-tools/idea/.idea/ant.xml
patching file dev-tools/idea/.idea/modules.xml
patching file dev-tools/idea/.idea/workspace.xml
Hunk #2 FAILED at 357.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file dev-tools/idea/.idea/workspace.xml.rej
patching file dev-tools/idea/lucene/analysis/opennlp/opennlp.iml
patching file dev-tools/maven/lucene/analysis/opennlp/pom.xml.template
patching file dev-tools/maven/lucene/analysis/pom.xml.template
patching file lucene/analysis/README.txt
patching file lucene/analysis/build.xml
.....................
..........................
kenStream.java
patching file solr/contrib/analysis-extras/README.txt
patching file solr/contrib/analysis-extras/build.xml
patching file solr/contrib/analysis-extras/ivy.xml
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #1 succeeded at 25 with fuzz 1.
```

Also after applying the patch I couldn't find the folder *solr/contrib/opennlp*. I checked the patch file and also couldn't find *diff --git* related to that folder.

Overlooking all these, I ran *ant clean compile* but was unable to generate 
*lucene-analyzers-opennlp-5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar* and *solr-opennlp-5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*.

If someone has **link to download jar**, kindly share it in comments.

This is the content of *workspace.xml.rej* file:

```
--- dev-tools/idea/.idea/workspace.xml
+++ dev-tools/idea/.idea/workspace.xml
@@ -357,49 +365,50 @@
       <module name="server" />
     </configuration>

-    <list size="42">
+    <list size="43">
       <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Lucene core" />
       <item index="1" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-common" />
       <item index="2" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-icu" />
       <item index="3" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-kuromoji" />
       <item index="4" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-morfologik" />
-      <item index="5" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-phonetic" />
-      <item index="6" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-smartcn" />
-      <item index="7" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-stempel" />
-      <item index="8" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-uima" />
-      <item index="9" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module backward-codecs" />
-      <item index="10" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module benchmark" />
-      <item index="11" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module classification" />
-      <item index="12" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module codecs" />
-      <item index="13" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module expressions" />
-      <item index="14" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module facet" />
-      <item index="15" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module grouping" />
-      <item index="16" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module highlighter" />
-      <item index="17" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module join" />
-      <item index="18" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module memory" />
-      <item index="19" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module misc" />
-      <item index="20" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module queries" />
-      <item index="21" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module queryparser" />
-      <item index="22" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module replicator" />
-      <item index="23" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module sandbox" />
-      <item index="24" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module spatial" />
-      <item index="25" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module spatial-extras" />
-      <item index="26" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module spatial3d" />
-      <item index="27" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module suggest" />
-      <item index="28" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr core" />
-      <item index="29" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr analysis-extras contrib" />
-      <item index="30" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr clustering contrib" />
-      <item index="31" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr dataimporthandler contrib" />
-      <item index="32" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr dataimporthandler-extras contrib" />
-      <item index="33" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr extraction contrib" />
-      <item index="34" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr map-reduce contrib" />
-      <item index="35" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr morphlines-cell contrib" />
-      <item index="36" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr morphlines-core contrib" />
-      <item index="37" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr langid contrib" />
-      <item index="38" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr uima contrib" />
-      <item index="39" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr velocity contrib" />
-      <item index="40" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solrj" />
-      <item index="41" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="Application.solrcloud" />
+      <item index="5" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-opennlp" />
+      <item index="6" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-phonetic" />
+      <item index="7" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-smartcn" />
+      <item index="8" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-stempel" />
+      <item index="9" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module analyzers-uima" />
+      <item index="10" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module backward-codecs" />
+      <item index="11" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module benchmark" />
+      <item index="12" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module classification" />
+      <item index="13" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module codecs" />
+      <item index="14" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module expressions" />
+      <item index="15" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module facet" />
+      <item index="16" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module grouping" />
+      <item index="17" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module highlighter" />
+      <item index="18" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module join" />
+      <item index="19" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module memory" />
+      <item index="20" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module misc" />
+      <item index="21" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module queries" />
+      <item index="22" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module queryparser" />
+      <item index="23" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module replicator" />
+      <item index="24" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module sandbox" />
+      <item index="25" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module spatial" />
+      <item index="26" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module spatial-extras" />
+      <item index="27" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module spatial3d" />
+      <item index="28" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Module suggest" />
+      <item index="29" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr core" />
+      <item index="30" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr analysis-extras contrib" />
+      <item index="31" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr clustering contrib" />
+      <item index="32" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr dataimporthandler contrib" />
+      <item index="33" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr dataimporthandler-extras contrib" />
+      <item index="34" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr extraction contrib" />
+      <item index="35" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr langid contrib" />
+      <item index="36" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr map-reduce contrib" />
+      <item index="37" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr morphlines-cell contrib" />
+      <item index="38" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr morphlines-core contrib" />
+      <item index="39" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr uima contrib" />
+      <item index="40" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solr velocity contrib" />
+      <item index="41" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JUnit.Solrj" />
+      <item index="42" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="Application.solrcloud" />
     </list>
   </component>
 </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did, based on the informations retrieved from [LUCENE-2899](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2899) ticket was the following :

```
git checkout releases/lucene-solr/6.1.0
```

(last developments for this ticket were performed a few months ago)

Afterwards I have applied the patch (via intellij IDEA), and can't clearly say why I had to manually add the lines 176-177

```
/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools = 1.6.0
/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-maxent = 3.0.3
```

to the file lucene-solr/lucene/ivy-versions.properties

After doing this, I could run successfully:

```
ant clean compile
```